# Downloading all images without src tag from website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm **scraping** images from websites. I'm locating them by src, but what if they don't have src tag? How should I get them? Right now utilizing such code

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import os

def url_to_page_name(url):
    parsed = urlparse(str(url))
    return parsed.netloc

def get_images_job(page_url):
    """Request given page and extract images"""
    directory_name = url_to_page_name(page_url)
    response = requests.get(page_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    img_tags = soup.find_all('img')

    urls = [img['src'] for img in img_tags]

    if not os.path.exists(directory_name):
        os.makedirs(directory_name)

    for url in urls:
        file_name = re.search(r'/([\w_-]+[.](jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|webp|svg))$', url)

        if file_name:
            file_name = file_name.group(1)

            with open(os.path.join(f'{directory_name}/' + file_name), 'wb') as f:
                if 'http' not in url:
                    # sometimes an image source can be relative
                    # if it is provide the base url which also happens
                    # to be the site variable atm.
                    url = '{}{}'.format(page_url, url)
                response = requests.get(url)
                f.write(response.content)
                
get_images_job("https://pixabay.com/")
```

And what if?

- they are used as background

```
background="img/tile.jpg"
```

- They can be located inside CSS
- They can be masked as base64

Comment: What if somebody used uppercase for "img", "src", or the file extension? You will just have to bite the bullet and write code to cover all cases.

Comment: Can you show example code of an image without an src tag? Somehow the image needs to be located...

Comment: @wp78de When they are inside CSS?

<body bgcolor="#000000" background="img/tile.jpg" text="#33ffcc" link="#cc99ff" vlink="#66cccc" alink="#ff0066">

Comment: I don't know what you are aiming for but have you tried some website downloader tools like HTTrack?

Comment: Well I have to do this via python, but it makes me wonder about httrack-py and other connections. i will see